# Magento 2.2 Not Loading theme and blocks

Tags: magento2, theme, magento2.2, static-block, magento2.2.2

I have created a magento 2.2 application using composer. Everything working fine with Luma Theme.
Next Step I need to extend the template.

> app / design / frontend /< Vendor name> / < Theme Name> /

Here I have created `etc/view.xml`, `media` folder, `web` folder, `registration.php`, `theme.xml`.

Then Created a `Magento_theme` folder and copied all files from

> vendor / magento / module-theme / view / frontend/

to the folder just created and edited `theme.xml` , `registration.php` 
and cleared cache and also applied `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

Then I login to backend I have seen the newly created theme in backend and applied the theme. Then I Changed Logo through Backend. Everything works fine.

But I need to edit `header.phtml` and I have edited the `header.phtml` in

> app / design / frontend/< Vendor name>/ < Theme Name > / Magento_theme / templates / html

It doesn't make any change in frontend. I have cleared `cache`, `setup-upgrade` everything as devdocs in magento. But No Changes. At the same time I just tried to edit the `header.phtml` in

> vendor / magento / module-theme / view / frontend / templates / html /

Its working and page changes. I Have Googled a lot and Tried Everything. But I didn't know what is wrong.

The steps I have done is
[Create Custom theme in Magento 2](https://magenticians.com/create-custom-theme-magento-2/)

Comment: this might be a typo, but the override directory need to be `Magento_Theme` and not `Magento_theme`. Check that, everything else seems to look right.

Answer (score 1):

Its a typo. Changed `Module_theme` to `Module_Theme` and working Fine.